# 502 error on request for static *.js files from a function that wraps an Express application

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

We are serving static files through a Firebase Function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist'))

exports.staticFiles = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Our `dist/` directory contains two files:

```
dist/
  index.html
  app.js
```

A request to `our-project.cloudfunctions.net/staticFiles/index.html` serves the expected HTML file. A request to `our-project.cloudfunctions.net/staticFiles/app.js` returns a 502 error.

How can we serve a simple *.js file from a Firebase Function?

#### Additional Details

- We are on the Blaze plan.
- The logs says: Function execution took 922 ms, finished with status: 'response error'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file size limit:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits

> Max uncompressed HTTP response size: 10MB.

[image]